# React-native-modal - Unexpected Token with Jest using TransformIgnorePatterns

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I'm trying to run a test with Jest on a React Native Component.
Using `react-native-modal`. I'm new on Jest and general unit testing, so I'm not sure how to fix this problem.

I even add:
`transformIgnorePatterns` property on the setup but the problem remains the same.

My Goal is to test property the Modal component.

Actual test:

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import BottomModalComponent from './BottomModalComponent';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('renders BottomModalComponent.js', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<BottomModalComponent isVisible={false} />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

---

**.babelrc** setup

```
// File-relative configuration
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
  ],
  "presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
  ],
  "retainLines": true
}
```

Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    ...
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "8",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"
  },
```

**babel.config.js**

```
// Project-wide configuration
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
};
```

This is how my **package.json** looks like with the Jest setup:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|react-native-modal)/)"
    ]
  },
```

This is my **error** when I run `npm run test`

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

SyntaxError: /project_name/node_modules/react-native-modal/src/index.js: Unexpected token (470:8)

      468 |       this.props.useNativeDriver &&
      469 |       !this.state.showContent ? (
    > 470 |         <animatable.View />
          |         ^
      471 |       ) : (
      472 |         children
      473 |       );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE (FIX)**

After debugging a while, I noticed the problem was I had to add to **Project wide configuration (babel.config.js)**:

```
"presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
  ]
```

Since I only added this line to the local environment `.bablerc`, this cause the problem on how to transpile babel the JSX react native components.

So, since both my babel setup was the same, I can get rid off **babel.config.js** and everything works fine.